# Upload and encrypt a file using Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http

Tags: zend-framework, encryption, upload

In Zend Framework documentation titled "[Filters for Zend_File_Transfer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html)", it said file can be encrypted and saved as a different name using the **filename** option.

> This filter supports one additional option which can be used to save the encrypted file with another filename. Set the **filename** option to change the filename where the encrypted file will be stored. If you suppress this option, the encrypted file will overwrite the original file.

How do I specify the filename option? I tried:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->addFilter('Encrypt', array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => 'mykey'), 'file.txt');
```

and

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->addFilter('Encrypt', array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => 'mykey', 'filename' => 'file.txt'));
```

both don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look into `Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php` and it does not seem that **filename** is a valid option for this adapter.
Maybe this is a Bug in the Documentation.
Instead you could use the **Rename**-Filter to change the filename.

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

$upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/file.txt'));
$upload->addFilter('Decrypt', array('adapter' => 'mcrypt', 'key' => 'mykey'));

$upload->receive();
```